# Passing string into Cython functions

Tags: python, string, cython

The past few days I've been experimenting with Cython and I have a quick questions regarding the way c / cython handles strings as character arrays / pointers:

```
def function(char *string):
    for i in xrange(len(string)):
        print string[i]
        print &string[i]
```

Now for example, when I compile and run the code, with `"abc"` as an argument, I get the following answer:

> 97
>
> abc
>
> 98
>
> bc
>
> 99
>
> c

Now my questions are:

- Why does cython print out the ascii value for each character in `string[i]`?
- Why does cython print out the suffix of the string starting at index `i` in `&string[i]`?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I believe the Cython docs recommend taking strings as `str`, not `char *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Python 3 `bytes`, when you index a `char *` in Cython, [Cython treats the `char` at that index as a numeric value, not text](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/strings.html#single-bytes-and-characters). That's why `print string[i]` prints a number.

The behavior of `print &string[i]` is inherited from C. If the `char *` points to the following null-terminated string:

```
 |
 v
+-+-+-+-+
|a|b|c| |
+-+-+-+-+
```

then `&string[1]` is a `char *` that points here:

```
   |
   v
+-+-+-+-+
|a|b|c| |
+-+-+-+-+
```

which is *also* a null-terminated string, this one having characters `bc` in it. When you `print` it, Cython prints `bc`.

The [Cython docs](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/strings.html) recommend not using `char *`s:

> Generally speaking: unless you know what you are doing, avoid using C strings where possible and use Python string objects instead.